# React application npm error while installation

Tags: reactjs, npm, installation

I have React application but as I run npm install it throws me an error:

```
λ npm install

> iltorb@2.4.5 install c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\new-design-backend\node_modules\iltorb
> node ./scripts/install.js || node-gyp rebuild

info looking for cached prebuild @ C:\Users\vladi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_prebuilds\0a16f1-iltorb-v2.4.5-node-v67-win32-x64.tar.gz
http request GET https://github.com/nstepien/iltorb/releases/download/v2.4.5/iltorb-v2.4.5-node-v67-win32-x64.tar.gz
http 404 https://github.com/nstepien/iltorb/releases/download/v2.4.5/iltorb-v2.4.5-node-v67-win32-x64.tar.gz
WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=11.15.0 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=win32)

c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\new-design-backend\node_modules\iltorb>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Program Files\Python37\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                                ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:299:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:193:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:999:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:266:5)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\new-design-backend\node_modules\iltorb
gyp ERR! node -v v11.15.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\laravel-mix\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\jest-haste-map\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! iltorb@2.4.5 install: `node ./scripts/install.js || node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the iltorb@2.4.5 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\vladi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-27T08_59_47_560Z-debug.log
```

Does anybody knows what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Its trying to get `https://github.com/nstepien/iltorb/releases/download/v2.4.5/iltorb-v2.4.5-node-v67-win32-x64.tar.gz`, but as you can see in the list `v67` is not there (anymore?): https://github.com/nstepien/iltorb/releases/tag/v2.4.5

If you can, it might help to delete the package-lock.json file and run `npm install` again, so it will get the latest versions instead of the one in your lock file.

Comment: It make sense but still the same error. It is not in the main package.json. I dont know which package depends on it.